# PostgreSQL: using variable in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a bunch of schemas in a loop.  I have something like this:

```
FOR i in 0 .. num_schemas LOOP
    schema_name := 'test' || i;
    CREATE SCHEMA testschema;
    CREATE TABLE testschema.testtable (
        test_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        test_address VARCHAR
    );

END LOOP;
```

But, this is not working; it tries to create a schema with the literal name 'testschema', instead of test0, test1... test'n'.  So, how can I use a variable in this sort of query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that. But instead of prefixing each table, I would change the current schema after creating it. That way you don't need to prefix every table you create:

```
FOR i in 0 .. num_schemas LOOP
    schema_name := 'test' || i;
    execute 'CREATE SCHEMA '||schema_name;
    execute 'set search_path = '||schema_name;
    CREATE TABLE testtable ( -- this will be created in the just created schema
        test_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        test_address VARCHAR
    );
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of `execute` command.
instead of `CREATE SCHEMA testschema` you can specify `execute 'CREATE SCHEMA '|| schema_name`;